# Using custom validators on md-error with mdAutocomplete and md-input-container. (Material 2)

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to use `md-error` tag to display error messages on an mdAutocomplete. I am using Angular with Material 2 components. The `md-error` message is displayed for built-in validators like `required`. However, I also want to display another error message with `md-error` when `No Matching Records are found` (basically when user types something which is not there in the dropdown). So, I tried having another `md-error` with an `*ngIf` but this error message is never shown. I googled about it and looks like the solution is to have a custom validation method or Directive. Material 2 provides a way to have custom validation method but I am not able to use it with my `template based form`. Could anyone provide me an example of using custom validation on a template based form using `md-error`?

Sample Code:

> This didn't work:

```html
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput
         placeholder="Currency Type"
         [(ngModel)]="policyObj.cost.premium.currencyType.name"
         [mdAutocomplete]="premiumCurrencyTypeAuto"
         [disabled]="disable"
         (keydown)="PanelOptions($event, policyObj.cost.premium.currencyType, filteredPremiumCurrencyType, premiumCurrencyTypeAuto)"
         (ngModelChange)="filteredPremiumCurrencyType = filterCurrency(policyObj.cost.premium.currencyType.name)"
         name="currency_type1" required>
     <md-error>This field is required</md-error>
     <md-error *ngIf="filteredPremiumCurrencyType?.length === 0"> No Matching
        Records Found!</md-error>
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #premiumCurrencyTypeAuto="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <md-option *ngFor="let ct of filteredPremiumCurrencyType" [value]="ct">
    {{ ct.name }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

I tried looking at [Material 2 - Custom Error Matcher](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#custom-error-matcher) but was not sure on how to use it in my case with template based forms. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`errorStateMatcher` should work just the same with template and reactive forms. Something like this should work for your use case:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput [errorStateMatcher]="myErrorStateMatcher.bind(this)" ... >
  <md-error *ngIf="policyObj.cost.premium.currencyType.name === ''">This field is required</md-error>
  <md-error *ngIf="filteredPremiumCurrencyType?.length === 0" No Matching Records Found!</md-error>
</md-input-container>


function myErrorStateMatcher(control, form): boolean {
  if (this.filteredPremiumCurrencyType && !this.filteredPremiumCurrencyType.length) {
    return true;
  }

  // Error when invalid control is touched, or submitted
  const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
  return !!(control.invalid && (control.touched || isSubmitted)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. I tried the way you have mentioned but then it displays both the `md-error` messages. How can I have a `*ngIf` on the second md-error as shown in above code snippet.

Comment: Add an *ngIf to the required: `<md-error *ngIf="currency_type1.errors?.required"> 
  This field is required
</md-error>` seemed to work when I tried it, if it works, Will can probably update that to answer :)

Comment: Updated! Impossible to know if I got the details right, but @mrsan22, just use *ngIf on the errors however you wish

Comment: Thanks guys...having `*ngIf` on the required worked.

Comment: @WillHowell I have tried the way you told but getting some issue . can you please help me out.If needed i will start a separate thread for that